# Android : MainActivity doesn't receive update from Worker

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, android-workmanager, worker

I have an Android **Worker** receiving AMQP messages from a broker and I want the worker to send an update to the **main activity** each time a message is received (to update the UI).
I am using the **setProgressAsync** function to send the update, and an observer to receive it.
The thing is that I never receive anything... I pass inside the observer function but only at start, not when I send an update.

Here is my code (Kotlin) :

*MainActivity.kt* :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        val communicationWorkRequest: WorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<CommunicationWorker>().build()

        workManager.enqueue(communicationWorkRequest)
        workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(communicationWorkRequest.id)
        .observe(this, Observer { workInfo: WorkInfo? ->
            var value = 0;

            if (workInfo != null) {
                value = workInfo.progress.getInt(CommunicationWorker.Progress, 0)
            }

            // I am supposed to receive the number 44 from the Worker
            Toast.makeText(this, "Value received: $value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })

        setContent {
            WearApp("Android")
        }
    }
}
```

*CommunicationWorker.kt* :

```
class CommunicationWorker(appContext: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(appContext, params) {
    companion object {
         const val Progress: String = "MyProgressId"
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val factory = ConnectionFactory()
        factory.host = "192.168.1.32"
        factory.username = "admin"
        factory.password = "admin"
        val connection = factory.newConnection()
        val channel = connection.createChannel()

        val consumer = object : DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            override fun handleDelivery(consumerTag: String, envelope: Envelope, properties: AMQP.BasicProperties, body: ByteArray) {
                setProgressAsync(Data.Builder().putInt(Progress, 44).build()); // Send the number 44 to the UI when I receive a message
            }
        }
        channel.basicConsume("epi.tab", true, consumer)

        Object().wait()

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

I want to precise that I am sure that I reach the reception callback when I receive a message (I break in debug mode).

I Don't know if it is important but my device is a Galaxy Watch 6 under Wear OS 4.

I am probably doing something wrong but I am stuck and none of my research give me a response...